# Convergence of a special series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Explore the convergence of a series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((n+1)!)^{n}}{2! \: 4!\dots (2n)!}$$

Could you give ideas how to solve problem?

Comment: It's not clear what's going on in the denominator

Comment: Oh, yes, I fix a mistake.

Comment: Have you tried the root test?

Comment: @HansEngler, okey, but then I don't know what to do with denominator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the *ratio* test for

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((n+1)!)^{n}}{2! \: 4!\dots (2n)!}$$
as follows:
$$L =\lim _{n\to \infty }\left|{\frac {a_{{n+1}}}{a_{n}}}\right|.$$

- if $L < 1,\,$ then the series converges absolutely;
- if $L > 1,\,$ then the series does not converge;
- if $L = 1,\,$ or the limit fails to exist, then the test is inconclusive, because there exist both convergent and divergent series that satisfy this case.

in your case, $$L =\lim _{n\to \infty }\left|{\frac {a_{{n+1}}}{a_{n}}}\right| =\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{((n+2)!)^{n+1}}{2! \: 4!\dots (2(n+1))!}}{\dfrac{((n+1)!)^{n}}{2! \: 4!\dots (2n)!}}\right)$$

Comment: After the cancellations, we have
$$
L = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+2)^n(n+2)!}{(2(n+1))!} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+2)^n}{(n+3)(n+4) \cdots (2n+2)}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes, I have same result. Thus limit is??

Comment: Well, your original question was for hints, not for solutions.  A lot of users here are hesitant to work through the full problem being asked about, especially if the asker hasn't shown their own sufficiently thorough attempt.  In any case, we should arrive at the conclusion that $L = 0$, but doing so is a bit tricky.

Comment: Certainly, however, it suffices to show that $L \leq 1/2$, which is easy to see by noting that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+2)^n}{(n+3)(n+4) \cdots (2n+2)} \leq 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+2)^n}{(n+2)^{n-1}(2n+2)}
$$

Comment: In fact, we can similarly show that for **any** integer $k \geq 1$, 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+2)^n}{(n+3)(n+4) \cdots (2n+2)} \leq
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+2)^n}{(n+2)^{n-k}(2n + 2 - k)^k} = \frac 1{2^k}
$$
which is in fact sufficient for us to determine the true limit of $L = 0$